# dpkg: error processing package glibc (--configure)

Tags: apt, 18.04, upgrade, glibc

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and, recently, every time I try to `sudo apt-get upgrade` the following occurs:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up glibc (2.27-1) ...
chown: invalid user: ‘builder:builder’
chown: invalid user: ‘builder:builder’
dpkg: error processing package glibc (--configure):
 installed glibc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 glibc
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Even if I try to `sudo apt autoremove` the same problem occurs.

I tried to Google this problem but I couldn't manage to solve it.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

---

== Edit ==

When I run `dpkg -l libc6` I get:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                               Version                Architecture           Description
+++-==================================-======================-======================-=========================================================================
ii  libc6:amd64                        2.27-3ubuntu1          amd64                  GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6:i386                         2.27-3ubuntu1          i386                   GNU C Library: Shared libraries
```

And when I do `apt policy libc6` I get:

```
libc6:
  Installed: 2.27-3ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2.27-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2.27-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

---

== Edit 2 ==

The output for `apt-cache policy glibc` is:

```
glibc:
  Installed: 2.27-1
  Candidate: 2.27-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.27-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Is this some kind of containerized (docker?) system?

Comment: hi @steeldriver No, it's not a docker system.

Comment: OK then sorry I have no idea why it would be trying to chown things to a `builder:builder` user/group. I hope someone else can think of something.

Comment: ... just one other thought, can you [edit] your question to include the output of `dpkg -l libc6` and `apt policy libc6` please

Comment: Of course! I just added what you asked

Comment: The package `glibc` does not officially exist in Ubuntu, so why is your system trying to install it? Maybe `apt-cache policy glibc` will tell us.

Comment: Sorry for the late response @fkraiem. I edited my post with the output for that.

Comment: It tells us that you have it installed, but not where it comes from. So, do you know how it got into your system and whether you really need it? Most likely you don't need it and should remove it (`sudo apt remove glibc`).

Comment: Thank you very much @fkraiem. I removed glibc and now everything seems alright.
I might have installed glibc by mistake and I don't have memory of that.

Comment: Great, you can now answer your own question. :)

Comment: yes! I will do that. Thank you again @fkraiem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @fkraiem, I finally solved the problem by simply removing `glibc`.

As @fkraiem said in the comments above, the package `glibc` does not officially exist in Ubuntu. I might have installed it, even though I don't remember when. So, it's most likely that I don't need it and should remove it.

After removing it everything seems fine and working normally again.